# How to install zlibsrc in pip

Tags: python-3.x, zlib

When I tried run an `.py` file, I will get this error:

```
No module named 'zlibsrc'
```

I ran the `.py` file and i encounter  `No module named 'zlibsrc'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `No module named ...` error message often means one of two things. Either the module is not installed (or at least not in the default paths), or the name of the module contains spelling mistakes.

From your question it sounds like you are trying to run already written code, so the cause is likely the first in this case.

I quickly googled `zlibsrc`, it appears to contain [malicious code](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-PYTHON-ZLIBSRC-2977575) and seems to [have been removed from the Python Package Index](https://thehackernews.com/2022/08/10-credential-stealing-python-libraries.html) because of it.

If you really want to run the code sent to you, a quick google will point you in the right direction of a pip install command. But I highly recommend you don't install the package.

Comment: I stopped trying commenting that file. Thanks for everything.